# AndroiBox of AndroPytool did not work

Tags: docker, malware

When I ran andropytool on Ubuntu 18.04, an error occurred that Androibox could not work

'''
(droidbox_env) root@d8e5070d137a:/#  cd AndroPyTool/
(droidbox_env) root@d8e5070d137a:/AndroPyTool# python androPyTool.py -s /Documents/malwareAnalistic/apks -all

> > > > AndroPyTool -- STEP 1: Filtering apks

1 apks found. Processing...
100%|#########################################################################################| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 14.62it/s]
TOTAL VALID APKS: 1
TOTAL INVALID APKS: 0

> > > > AndroPyTool -- STEP 3: Filtering BW and MW

0%|                                                                                                 | 0/1 [00:00

> > > > AndroPyTool -- STEP 4: Launching FlowDroid

100%|#########################################################################################| 1/1 [00:11<00:00, 11.79s/it]

> > > > AndroPyTool -- STEP 5: Processing FlowDroid outputs

100%|########################################################################################| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 702.68it/s]
Success!!
Output folder: /Documents/malwareAnalistic/apks/FlowDroid_processed/

> > > > AndroPyTool -- STEP 6: Execute DroidBox

Killing current active emulators...

#

100.00% NEW APK: /Documents/malwareAnalistic/apks/samples//787481b5d3cb2d48098f12db3012347e.apk

#

Starting emulator 
STARTING  EMULATOR IN NON GUI MODE...
ADB DEVICE RUNNING 
subprocess called
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon: Connection refused
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon: Connection refused
error: cannot connect to daemon: Connection refused
Waiting until boot is completed
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
error: device '(null)' not found
Boot not completed
'''

Comment: Does this really have to run as root ?

Comment: I used root privileges to run it

Comment: Why did you use root privileges to run it, it is almost always wrong.